# Deploy PMD report into tomcat server using maven plugins

Tags: maven, pmd

I want to deploy PMD report into tomcat server using maven plugins.
    I have tried site plugins with distributionmanagement.

```
<distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>site.deployments</id>
            <name>Site deployments</name>
            <url>dav:http://10.216.179.54/sites/${artifactId}/</url>
        </site>
```

Comment: but its not working any one can help me to come out this problem , erros occure while deploying site- 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy (default-deploy) on project springMVCTest: Execution def
ault-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.
apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org

Comment: Check out this: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-site-with-mvn-site-deploy-webdav-example/

You probably need to define a wagon-provider for DAV, so that maven can use DAV -> http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit/